# Resource-Server for IdentityServer 4

Tags: server, resources, identityserver4

My task is to implement a resource server(RS) for IdentityServer4(IS4). The RS should fetch data from a database and send the necessary information as a json object back to the caller (client). This is needed because we have to return complex objects.

I already setup IS4 succesfully and its already running in Docker for testing purpose. I also setup the needed database.

My understanding of the flow would be, the user requests data from the RS sending the access-token, the RS then validates the token, checking if the caller is allowed to access the api using the IS4, if everything is okay the RS returns the data to the caller.

My problem is, as I'm new to this subject, how would I implement a RS? Do I create an API which is added as a scope to the user? Or is there a RS already implemented in IS4?

Answer (score 0):

So yes you'll need to write your own API to serve your own resources, IdentityServer will only manage your identities for you (as well as handling external logins if that's what you need). I'd recommend going to the [IdentityServer docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/) and working through the quick starts in order as shown below:

[image]

This will give you a good start but you'll then need to go away and research APIs more generally, there's a tonne of good info online about building (RESTful) APIs. You may find it useful to sign up to something like [PluralSight](https://www.pluralsight.com/) and work through a couple of their courses, they're often very good.

One other thing to bear in mind is that IdentityServer is for identity, in other words Authentication and not specifically for Authorisation so you may need to add something for this. You can of course use a users identity for authorisation purposes but in most cases you'll probably need to augment the info you store about their identity to authorise them for access. See [this link](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/06/16/relationship-between-identityserver-and-authorizationserver/) for more info around this topic.